# How to display custom markers for grouped points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Given a HighStock chart series (scatter) that may have grouped points, my goal is to display a custom maker (different than the regular point marker) for them.

I have tried the following code:

```
series.points.forEach(p => {
            if (p && p.dataGroup && p.dataGroup.length > 1) {
                p.update({
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        fillColor: "black",
                        lineColor: "black",
                        radius: 20
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
```

It doesnt work however since it throws error 15. I understand that grouped points are not allowed to be updated (see https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5147).

So, how else can I achieve my goal? Any ideas?

Comment: I think if you narrow down your question and add a language tag, it stands a higher chance of getting good answers :)

Comment: I think that you can update colour of entire series instead of every point in your chart. You may use Series.update() in this case. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwd7jcwz/1/

Comment: Please, look at this topic on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349637/highstock-single-line-series-dynamically-create-marker-based-on-a-trigger. As you noticed, it could be hard to update a point when data grouping is applied. Try solution from a link above. If you still will be facing problems, please let us know. Also, it would be good if you would post your example on jsfiddle.